# Compile wireshark 64bit failed under win7 with Cmake,what is the cause?

Tags: compilation, cmake, wireshark

I tried to compile wireshark at WIN7 with CMAKE under 64bit option,however the result is failed
I can not figure out the reason,could you help me to have a check.I appreciate any suggestions 
from you.Thanks a lot,i like this platform.below is the environment setting and command.

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64

set WIRESHARK_BASE_DIR=E:\Wireshark_Plugin\SecVersion\wireshark-master

set WIRESHARK_CYGWIN_INSTALL_PATH==E:\Software\Cygwin\bin

set WIRESHARK_TARGET_PLATFORM=win64

set QT5_BASE_DIR=E:\Software\QT\5.6\msvc2013_64

set  VISUALSTUDIOVERSION=12.0

set MSVC_VARIANT=MSVC2013EE

e:

cd  E:\Wireshark_Plugin\SecVersion\wsbuild

cmake -DENABLE_CHM_GUIDES=on -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64" ..\wireshark-master
pause

E:\Wireshark_Plugin\SecVersion\wsbuild>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Vi
sual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64

-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0

-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0

-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64

-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64

-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting CXX compile features

-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

-- Generating build using CMake 3.5.2

-- Found POWERSHELL: C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe

-- Building for win64 using Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64

Working in E:\Wireshark_Plugin\SecVersion\wireshark-master\wireshark-win64-libs
Tag 2016-05-10 found. Skipping.

-- No custom file found in E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master

-- Configuration types: Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo

-- CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO: /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG

-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO: /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG

-- V: 2.1.0-git, MaV: 2, MiV: 1, PL: 0, EV: -git.

-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python27/python.exe (found version "2.7.8")

-- Found python module asn2wrs: E:\Wireshark_Plugin\SecVersion\wireshark-master\
tools\asn2wrs.py

-- Checking for c-compiler flag: /MP

-- Performing Test C__MP_VALID

-- Performing Test C__MP_VALID - Success

-- Checking for c-compiler flag: /Zo

-- Performing Test C__Zo_VALID

-- Performing Test C__Zo_VALID - Success

-- Checking for c-compiler flag: /w34295 /w34189

-- Performing Test C__w34295_w34189_VALID

-- Performing Test C__w34295_w34189_VALID - Success

-- Checking for c++-compiler flag: /MP

-- Performing Test CXX__MP_VALID

-- Performing Test CXX__MP_VALID - Success

-- Checking for c++-compiler flag: /Zo

-- Performing Test CXX__Zo_VALID

-- Performing Test CXX__Zo_VALID - Success

-- Checking for c++-compiler flag: /w34295 /w34189

-- Performing Test CXX__w34295_w34189_VALID

-- Performing Test CXX__w34295_w34189_VALID - Success
statuscheck linker flag - test linker flags: -Wl,--as-needed

-- Performing Test WS_LD_FLAG_VALID0

-- Performing Test WS_LD_FLAG_VALID0 - Failed
statuscheck linker flag - test linker flags: -pie

-- Performing Test WS_LD_FLAG_VALID1

-- Performing Test WS_LD_FLAG_VALID1 - Failed

-- Looking for sys/types.h

-- Looking for sys/types.h - found

-- Looking for stdint.h

-- Looking for stdint.h - found

-- Looking for stddef.h

-- Looking for stddef.h - found

-- Check size of off64_t

-- Check size of off64_t - failed

-- Looking for fseeko

-- Looking for fseeko - not found

-- Looking for unistd.h

-- Looking for unistd.h - not found

-- Packagelist: AIRPCAP;CAP;CARES;GCRYPT;GEOIP;GLIB2;GMODULE2;GNUTLS;GTHREAD2;GT
K2;Gettext;Git;KERBEROS;LEX;LIBSSH;LUA;M;PCAP;POD;PORTAUDIO;Perl;PythonInterp;Qt
5Core;Qt5LinguistTools;Qt5Multimedia;Qt5PrintSupport;Qt5Svg;Qt5Widgets;Qt5WinExt
ras;SBC;SED;SETCAP;SH;SMI;WINSPARKLE;YACC;YAPP;ZLIB

-- Found AIRPCAP: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win6
4-libs/AirPcap_Devpack_4_1_0_1622/Airpcap_Devpack/include

-- AIRPCAP FOUND

-- AIRPCAP includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-w
in64-libs/AirPcap_Devpack_4_1_0_1622/Airpcap_Devpack/include

-- AIRPCAP libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64
-libs/AirPcap_Devpack_4_1_0_1622/Airpcap_Devpack/lib/airpcap.lib

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

-- Checking for one of the modules 'libcap'

-- Could NOT find CAP (missing:  CAP_LIBRARY CAP_INCLUDE_DIR)

-- CAP NOT FOUND

-- Found CARES: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-
libs/c-ares-1.11.0-win64ws/lib/libcares-2.lib

-- CARES FOUND

-- CARES includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win
64-libs/c-ares-1.11.0-win64ws/include

-- CARES libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-l
ibs/c-ares-1.11.0-win64ws/lib/libcares-2.lib

-- Found GCRYPT: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64
-libs/gnutls-3.2.15-2.9-win64ws/bin/libgcrypt-20.lib (found suitable version "1.
6.2", minimum required is "1.4.2")

-- GCRYPT FOUND

-- GCRYPT includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-wi
n64-libs/gnutls-3.2.15-2.9-win64ws/include

-- GCRYPT libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-
libs/gnutls-3.2.15-2.9-win64ws/bin/libgcrypt-20.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersi
on/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gnutls-3.2.15-2.9-win64ws/bin/libgpg-er
ror6-0.lib

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

-- Checking for one of the modules 'geoip'

-- Found GEOIP: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-
libs/GeoIP-1.6.6-win64ws/lib/libGeoIP-1.lib

-- Looking for GeoIP_country_name_by_ipnum_v6

-- Looking for GeoIP_country_name_by_ipnum_v6 - found

-- GEOIP FOUND

-- GEOIP includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win
64-libs/GeoIP-1.6.6-win64ws/include

-- GEOIP libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-l
ibs/GeoIP-1.6.6-win64ws/lib/libGeoIP-1.lib

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

-- Checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.0>=2.14.0'

-- Found GLIB2: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-
libs/gtk2/lib/glib-2.0.lib

-- GLIB2 FOUND

-- GLIB2 includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win
64-libs/gtk2/include/glib-2.0;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wi
reshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/glib-2.0/include

-- GLIB2 libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-l
ibs/gtk2/lib/glib-2.0.lib

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

-- Checking for one of the modules 'gmodule-2.0'

-- Found GMODULE2: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win
64-libs/gtk2/lib/gmodule-2.0.lib

-- GMODULE2 FOUND

-- GMODULE2 includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-
win64-libs/gtk2/include/glib-2.0

-- GMODULE2 libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win6
4-libs/gtk2/lib/gmodule-2.0.lib

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

-- Checking for one of the modules 'gnutls'

-- Found GNUTLS: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64

-libs/gnutls-3.2.15-2.9-win64ws/bin/libgnutls-28.lib (found suitable version "3.
2.15", minimum required is "2.12.0")

-- GNUTLS FOUND

-- GNUTLS includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-wi
n64-libs/gnutls-3.2.15-2.9-win64ws/include

-- GNUTLS libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-
libs/gnutls-3.2.15-2.9-win64ws/bin/libgnutls-28.lib

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

-- Checking for one of the modules 'gthread-2.0'

-- Found GTHREAD2: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win
64-libs/gtk2/lib/glib-2.0.lib

-- GTHREAD2 FOUND

-- GTHREAD2 includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-
win64-libs/gtk2/include/glib-2.0/glib

-- GTHREAD2 libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win6
4-libs/gtk2/lib/glib-2.0.lib

-- Found GTK2_GTK: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win
64-libs/gtk2/lib/gtk-win32-2.0.lib

-- GTK2 FOUND

-- GTK2 includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win6
4-libs/gtk2/include/gtk-2.0;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wire
shark-win64-libs/gtk2/include;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wi
reshark-win64-libs/gtk2/include/freetype2;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wiresha
rk-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/include/glib-2.0;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVers
ion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/glib-2.0/include;E:/Wireshark
_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/include/atk-1.0;E:
/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/include/
gdk-pixbuf-2.0;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-l
ibs/gtk2/include/cairo;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark
-win64-libs/gtk2/include/pango-1.0;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-mast
er/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/gtk-2.0/include

-- GTK2 libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-li
bs/gtk2/lib/glib-2.0.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wiresha
rk-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/gobject-2.0.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-
master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/atk-1.0.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/
wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/gmodule-2.0.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plug
in/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/gdk_pixbuf-2.0.lib;
E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/ca
iro.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk
2/lib/pango-1.0.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-wi
n64-libs/gtk2/lib/pangocairo-1.0.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-ma
ster/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/gdk-win32-2.0.lib;E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVers
ion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win64-libs/gtk2/lib/gtk-win32-2.0.lib

-- Could NOT find Gettext (missing:  GETTEXT_MSGMERGE_EXECUTABLE GETTEXT_MSGFMT_
EXECUTABLE)

-- GETTEXT NOT FOUND

-- Could NOT find Git (missing:  GIT_EXECUTABLE)

-- Git NOT FOUND

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

-- Checking for one of the modules 'krb5;mit-krb5;heimdal-krb5'

-- Found KERBEROS: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win
64-libs/kfw-3-2-2-x64-ws/lib/krb5_64.lib

-- Looking for heimdal_version

-- Looking for heimdal_version - not found

-- KERBEROS FOUND

-- KERBEROS includes: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-
win64-libs/kfw-3-2-2-x64-ws/include

-- KERBEROS libs: E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wireshark-master/Wireshark-win6
4-libs/kfw-3-2-2-x64-ws/lib/krb5_64.lib

CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindCygwin.cmake:59 (message):
  Cygwin installation path was not detected.  You can set it with
  WIRESHARK_CYGWIN_INSTALL_PATH environment variable.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/FindLEX.cmake:5 (INCLUDE)
  CMakeLists.txt:835 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wsbuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/Wireshark_Plugin/SecVersion/wsbuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Comment: Let me point you to the error: `CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindCygwin.cmake:59 (message): Cygwin installation path was not detected. You can set it with WIRESHARK_CYGWIN_INSTALL_PATH environment variable.`

Comment: Did you follow [WireShark: Win32/64: Step-by-Step Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html)?

Comment: Thanks sir, I will compile it again,as soon as I improve it.